# How do I make the arrow keys always able to move my character?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been making a laser tag game, and I want to (obviously) let my players move around. So, following a tutorial on YouTube, I have managed to let my player move! However, after I press a key the press the opposite, I cannot press the opposite again. By this, I mean, if I press the up arrow key, my character will go up WITHOUT STOPPING EVEN IF I STOP PRESSING THAT KEY. The only way to stop it is if I press the down key which will stop it. However, then, if I want my character to go down, my character won't move; it just stands there. The same goes for the left and right arrow keys - if I press right, it will move without stopping until the left arrow is pressed. Then, the left key ceases to work.

So I have **2** questions:

How can I make my character stop after lifting the key?

and

How can I make all the keys always work?

Thanks for your help!

code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
 
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
 
serv.listen(2000)
console.log("Server started.");
 
var SOCKET_LIST = {};
var PLAYER_LIST = {};

var Player = function(id) {
    var self = {
        x:250,
        y:250,
        id:id,
        number: "0",
        pressingRight:false,
        pressingLeft:false,
        pressingUp:false,
        pressingDown:false,
        maxSpd:10,
    }
    self.updatePosition = function(){
        if(self.pressingRight)
            self.x += self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingLeft)
            self.x -= self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingUp)
            self.y -= self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingDown)
            self.y += self.maxSpd;
    }
    return self;
}
 
var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.id = Math.random();
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

    var player = Player(socket.id);
    PLAYER_LIST[socket.id] = player
 
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
        delete PLAYER_LIST[socket.id];
    });

    socket.on('keyPress',function(data){
        if(data.inputId === 'left')
            player.pressingLeft = data.state;
        else if(data.inputId === 'right')
            player.pressingRight = data.state;
        else if(data.inputId === 'up')
            player.pressingUp = data.state;
        else if(data.inputId === 'down')
            player.pressingDown = data.state;
    });
 
});
 
setInterval(function(){
    var pack = [];
    for(var i in PLAYER_LIST){
        var player = PLAYER_LIST[i];
        player.updatePosition();
        pack.push({
            x:player.x,
            y:player.y,
            number:player.number
        });     
    }
    for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        socket.emit('newPositions',pack);
    }
 
 
 
 
},1000/25);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = '30px Arial';
     
        var socket = io();
     
        socket.on('newPositions',function(data){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
            for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++)
                ctx.fillText(data[i].number,data[i].x,data[i].y);       
        });
        document.onkeydown = function(event){
            if(event.keyCode === 39)    //d
                socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'right',state:true});
            else if(event.keyCode === 40)   //s
                socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'down',state:true});
            else if(event.keyCode === 37) //a
                socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'left',state:true});
            else if(event.keyCode === 38) // w
                socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'up',state:true});
    
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you fire and listen only to `keyPress`. You should also listen to `keyup` and set all `player.pressing...` to `false`.

Comment: @MoshFeu ok...could you give me an example in code?

Comment: Actually, I wrote a post about it :) I think that it's very similar to what you're doing - https://medium.com/@moshfeu/how-to-build-an-html5-games-controller-with-arduino-nodejs-and-socket-io-part-1-c5067647ca51?sk=dac4aac548da9bb12a52f4428a7fb279

Comment: Wow, that seems cool! Except...I'm not quite sure how to implement this in my code (forgive me, Im quite new to this)

Comment: actually i figured out what was wrong...its ok

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured out what was wrong. I had only listened to key down but not key up. This is code I needed to add:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 68)    //d
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'right',state:false});
        else if(event.keyCode === 83)   //s
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'down',state:false});
        else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'left',state:false});
        else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'up',state:false});
    }
```